# Plone setuphandler- In a setuphandler, how can I programatically add/create a folderish content type at root of Plonesite?

Tags: plone

I have have made a folderish content type called supplier_folder, which displays a list of suppliers that can be added under it, and their information.  I can add it through the navigation bar, but I would like to add it programatically during setup.

I have been following the tutorial on custom installer code (http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/genericsetup.html#custom-installer-code-setuphandlers-py) and have looked at creating objects programatically (http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/creating.html).

Unfortunately, the second article says I need to have a folder created.  How can I get around this and add the supplier_folder object at the Plone Site outside of a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, only users with role **Manager** or **Site Administrator** can add content to the root of the site; you can overcome this limitation in two ways:

1. by using the `_constructInstance` method as it [bypasses the permissions](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/creating.html#bypassing-permissions-when-creating-content-item) when creating an item
2. by [switching roles inside your code](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.api/docs/env.html#env-adopt-roles-example) with `plone.api.env.adopt_roles`

I personally prefer the second one.

you can see an example of a pretty complex `setuphandlers.py` in [interlegis.portalmodelo.policy](https://github.com/interlegis/interlegis.portalmodelo.policy/blob/master/src/interlegis/portalmodelo/policy/setuphandlers.py) package.

Comment: _constructInstance worked well.  It appears I didn't catch it in the Dexterity manual, but it is incredibly useful for Setup because like you said, it bypasses the permissions.

However, it seems for some reason that when I try to add content to the container (via addContentToContainer), I needed to change permission for the context in which the container is added to.  I easily changed the context (in my case, the site) using manage_permission.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Plone site, it's also creating some default content types.

Look at how Plone do: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/1471828ee97a8dd84396bad4a3286be514819869/Products/CMFPlone/setuphandlers.py#L119

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. The buildin mechanism is to use GenericSetup in combination with "structure" folder as described here: http://koansys.com/tech/create-plone-initial-content-with-generic-setup

In short you need the following:

1. Create a folder "structure" in your Generic Setup profile (in general, under profiles/default)
2. Create a .objects file with the following content: "suppliers,supplier_folder"
3. in "structure" create a folder "suppliers" with a .properties file and content:

   ```
   [DEFAULT]
   title = Suppliers
   description = Some usefull description text
   ```

As far as I remember this is ok for simple structures likes your. If you have complex structures with folders and sub-folders and want more specific control you probably need to write python code. I made some stuff here: https://github.com/collective/zettwerk.setup/blob/master/zettwerk/setup/structure.py

But zettwerk.setup is not yet released, but you should be able to integrate the structure.py right into your project. Than you can the handle_structure method into your setuphandlers.py and passing a structure dict like this:

```
handle_structure(portal, [{'id': 'suppliers', 'portal_type': 'supplier_folder'}])
```

The advantage of this method is, that you can also control metadata like workflow state, default page setting, portlets, local roles and some others.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wm.sampledata/0.3 lists also some extension products, that allows adding of sample data, which might be useful.